# Write rows to Excel through array

Tags: java, excel, loops, arraylist, while-loop

So I currently have this code that goes through a while loop and reads the following fields from a "result set object" (JDBC stuff).

Fields to read and populate: eNumber, eName.

```
while (rs.next()) {

        ArrayList<String> eRow = new ArrayList<String>();

        String eNumber = rs.getString("ENTRYNUMBER");
        String eventName = rs.getString("EVENTNAME");
        //String 
        System.out.println("entryNumber: " + eNumber + "\t" + "eventName: " +eName );

        eRow.add(eNumber);
        eRow.add(eName);
}
```

My question - how can I write the two variables to two different cells of the same row and then repeat in a while loop? Then export to excel. I figured I need an array but Im stuck after that.

Ex:

[image: LoopWriteExample]

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
eRow.add(eNumber+","+eName);
```

Comment: Need to write to eRow to an excel cell. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add both to the same index, probably using a delimiter:

```
eRow.add(eNumber + '#' + eName); // just chose '#' as unlikely to be used
```

Then you could transpose the array into a single column using the `eRow.toArray()` method and finally use Text to Columns to split the data out again.

Or you could loop over the arraylist (pre-warning, I'm *useless* as java so this may not actually run but should give you an idea of what I mean):

```
// ... your code

String[] splitVals;

for (int i = 1; i <= eRow.Count; i++){
    splitVals = eRow[i].Split('#');
    setCellValue(splitVals[0], i, 1);
    setCellValue(splitVals[1], i, 2);
}

// ... some more code ...

public void setCellValue(String val, int row, int col) {
    if (!this.isLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    Dispatch cellRef = Dispatch.invoke(activeSheet, "Cells", Dispatch.Get, new Object[]{++row, ++col}, new int[1]).toDispatch();
    Dispatch.put(cellRef, "Value", val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-write your code as follows.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eRow = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
while (rs.next()) {
        String eNumber = rs.getString("ENTRYNUMBER");
        String eName = rs.getString("EVENTNAME");
        //String 
        System.out.println("entryNumber: " + eNumber + "\t" + "eventName: " +eName );

        HashMap<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row.put(eNumber, eName);
        eRow.add(row);
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
You can loop through your eRow and write the values to a cvs file with something like below

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file.csv");
for (HashMap<String, String> map : eRow)
{
     for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
     {
         fw.write(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue() + " \n");
```

Comment: will try this. How to write the eRow to an Excel cell?

Comment: Can you add it to ur answer with the proper formatting? The comment has no spacing.